# Mongodb native connections from nodejs return undefined databases list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm just starting to use Mongodb without mongoose (to get away from the schemas), and wanted to create a simple module with various exported functions to use in the rest of my app. I've pasted the code below.

The problem I'm having is that the databasesList.databases comes back as undefined, and I'm not sure why. There should be 2 databases on my cluster, and one collection in each  database.

As a tangential question, I thought maybe I would check the collections instead (now commented out), but though I found this page (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/) the function getCollectionNames seems not to exist. Now I'm wondering if I'm using the wrong documentation and that is why my databases are coming back undefined.

````
const client = new MongoClient(uri)
const connection = client.connect( function (err, database) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else if (!database) console.log('Unknown error connecting to database');
    else {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB database server');
    }

});

module.exports = {
    getDatabaseList: function() {
        console.log('start ' + client);

        databasesList = client.db().admin().listDatabases();
        //collectionList = client.db().getCollectionNames();
        //console.log("Collections: " + collectionList);
    
        console.log("Databases: " + databasesList.databases);
        //databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
    }
}```
````

Comment: You need to refer the [MongoDB NodeJS Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/index.html) APIs for the appropriate methods. Sometimes there are different names in the driver version.

Comment: Thank you! I was indeed looking in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is correct Just need to change few things.

```
module.exports = {
    getDatabaseList: async function() {
        console.log('start ' + client);

        databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();
        //collectionList = await client.db().getCollectionNames();
        //console.log("Collections: " + collectionList);
    
        console.log("Databases: " + databasesList.databases);
        databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
    }
}
```

You have to declare **async** function and use **await** also.

The **async** and **await** keywords enable **asynchronous**, promise-based behaviour to be written in a cleaner style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

Comment: Ah, I added async and it immediately worked. It is much easier to do this than try to create, as you said, those long promise chains!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this modular approach to build your database access code:

**index.js:** Run your database application code, like list database names, collection names and read from a collection.

```
const connect = require('./database');
const dbFunctions = require('./dbFunctions');

const start = async function() {
    const connection = await connect();
    console.log('Connected...');
    const dbNames = await dbFunctions.getDbNames(connection);
    console.log(await dbNames.databases.map(e => e.name));
    const colls = await dbFunctions.getCollNames(connection, 'test');
    console.log(await colls.map(e => e.name));
    console.log(await dbFunctions.getDocs(connection, 'test', 'test'));
};

start();
```

**database.js:**: Create a connection object. This connection is used for all your database access code. In general, a single connection creates a *connection pool* and this can be used throughout a small application

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const opts = { useUnifiedTopology: true };

async function connect() {
    console.log('Connecting to db server...');
    return await MongoClient.connect(url, opts );
}

module.exports = connect;
```

**dbFunctions.js:**: Various functions to access database details, collection details and query a specific collection.

```
module.exports = {
    // return list of database names
    getDbNames: async function(conn) {
        return await conn.db().admin().listDatabases( { nameOnly: true } );
    },
    // return collections list as an array for a given database
    getCollNames: async function(conn, db) {
        return await conn.db(db).listCollections().toArray();
    },
    // return documents as an array for a given database and collection
    getDocs: async function(conn, db, coll) {
        return await conn.db(db).collection(coll).find().toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you intend to use all of these together? I see how database.js and dbFunctions.js fit together, but I'm not sure I understand why to run through index.js. Is that more of a initializer to collect some information for use in later queries? Also, I originally intended to use more of this approach, but then felt that I would need to initiate a connection (from database.js) for each file that might call into a function from dbFunctions.js. I'm struggling a bit with the idea of "global" values shared between files.

Comment: In general, `Index.js` is to be an initializer only. Here I showed the usage some of the database methods - this functionality is not to be done from the starter module (unless its a demo or testing the database APIs as in this case). The single database connection is used for all the functions. It is/can be passed to other modules. All this works fine if you extend this to use ExpressJS / routes / apis. Then you don''t have all those db method calls in the starter module - index.js will just be a starter program only.